# Table cell selection off by 1 pixel

Tags: javafx, tableview

**Problem**

The TableView's cell selection is off by 1 pixel. The selection covers the bottom/right grid lines, but not the top/left grid lines.

Here's a CSS to make this immediately visible

```
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-background: gray;
}
```

[image]

Here's a magnified look at the selection of a TableView in one of the JavaFX examples on the Oracle website:

[image]

In Oracle's example it may not be quite noticable, but if you choose different colors, it's very well obvious that there's something shifted.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to fix it? The selection should either cover all surrounding grid lines or none.

**Code**

Example code (taken from the Oracle examples, I only activated cell selection):

```
public class TableViewSample2 extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

I created an [issue request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40557) regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Visual Tweak to Place Selection Coloring Inside Cell Grid*

To achieve the effect you wish (the selection is completely inside the gray cell border), you can use the following css:

```
.table-cell:selected {
    -fx-border-color: transparent derive(-fx-color,5%) transparent transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 1 0, 1 2 2 1, 2 3 3 2;
}
```

[image: williams]

Normally when a row is selected the right border is set to the selection accent color (the blue color) rather than the default grey color.  The `derive(-fx-color,5%)` color is the default cell border, so when the cell is selected, for the updated css, we just keep that color.  We don't actually need to set the cell bottom border (I guess because there is a separate row css to handle that).

Then the cell background needs to shift one pixel in from the right and bottom (and the focus ring and the inner background inside the focus ring).  So the standard selected cell background coloring is changed to the updated form from the original form of `-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;`.

*Opinion*

I am pretty sure that the rendering of the table cells is as it is by design.  The grid lines in the table view are actually part of a cell's defined area, so there is no spacing or gap between cells and there is also no overlap of cells.  To achieve this design, the cell area does not include the top and left lines, but does include the bottom and right lines.  So, when the cell is selected and changes color to indicate it is selected, you see the top and left grid lines, but not the bottom and right grid lines.

Also, if you set the selection mode to multiple (`table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`), then the selection area looks a little weird with the inside grid selection visual tweak, because the grid shows through the multiple selection and the selection area is not one continuous color.

> I updated the question and added the css where the situation became immediately obvious.

Thanks for updating the question to include the color change css to make the alignment difference more visible - I was only updating the selection color and that didn't make the alignment difference as obvious as it does with your color change of the cell background for the entire table.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I couldn't post the example you asked in the comment earlier. I updated the question and added the css where the situation became immediately obvious. I don't think the multi-selection is weird with the css I provided. I figured that the overlapping of multiple selections would be a problem. In my opinion the selection should always cover all grid lines or none, but never only parts. So I guess it's just bad design from a visual point of view, from a technical point of view it may make sense.

Comment: You can create an [issue request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) linking back to this stack overflow question, if you would like to have a developer or designer look into it.

Comment: Thanks, I created an issue.

Comment: Please provide a link to the issue you created so that somebody who comes across this question could find it easily if they wished to do so.

Comment: Ok, here's the [link to the issue](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40557). I also updated the question with it. Off-Topic: Is it not possible on the jira site to format code segments? I tried with {code} from the jira help, but it didn't work. I also didn't see an option to add images.

Comment: The lack of code formatting is a limitation of the current Jira system used for Java issue tracking (also image attachments are disabled without privilege).  There is a [third party Syntax Highlighter available](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jira.plugin.syntaxhighlighter.macro.syntaxplugin), you could request on the [JavaFX mailing list](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/) to get the Syntax Highlighter plugin installed.  Note, I think for Java 9, the plan is to merge the JavaFX issue tracker into the main Java issue tracker (sometime in the next couple of months).